# The player is not showing in the window in [C++/SFML]

Tags: c++, sfml

I'm coding a game in c++ with SFML. I wrote the code for the player and the end goal and the grid, but when the game starts, the console shows that the player's coordinates are changing but the player it self is not showing or displaying in the window. Any one can help ? also the game is all about a player moving inside a grid. when the player collides (here this mean that the player is in the same grid tile ) with the End Goal.

**main.cpp**

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <SFML/System/Clock.hpp>
#include "Player.h"

float tileSize = 25.f;
sf::RectangleShape endGoal(sf::Vector2f(tileSize - tileSize / 10, tileSize - tileSize / 10));

Player player(tileSize);

int main()
{
    sf::Clock clock;

    
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(1080, 720), "Player & End Goal -  Grid Game");
    window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true);


    
    endGoal.setFillColor(sf::Color(0, 185, 0, 255));
    endGoal.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(0, 185, 0, 255));
    endGoal.setOutlineThickness(tileSize / 10);
    endGoal.setPosition(tileSize * 20, tileSize * 15);

    /////// Game Loop //////
    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        float dt = clock.restart().asSeconds();
        sf::Event evnt;
        while (window.pollEvent(evnt))
        {
            switch (evnt.type)
            {
            case sf::Event::Closed:
                std::cout << "Window has been closed." << std::endl;
                window.close(); // closes the window when the 'X' button gets pressed
            }
        }
        
        //Player Movement

        player.handleMovement();

        if (player.isPlayerColliding(endGoal)) {
            std::cout << "Player is colliding with End Goal.." << std::endl;
        }
        else {
            std::cout << "X" << std::endl;
        }

        window.clear(sf::Color::White);
        //Drawing The Grid
        for (int i = 0; i <= window.getSize().x / tileSize; i++) {
            
            for (int j = 0; j <= window.getSize().y / tileSize; j++) {
                sf::RectangleShape gridTile(sf::Vector2f(20.f, 20.f));
                gridTile.setSize(sf::Vector2f((float)tileSize, (float)tileSize));
                gridTile.setFillColor(sf::Color(210, 210, 210, 255));
                gridTile.setOutlineColor(sf::Color(155, 155, 155, 255));
                gridTile.setOutlineThickness(2.5f);
                gridTile.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(i * gridTile.getSize().x, j * gridTile.getSize().y));
                
                window.draw(gridTile);
            }
            
        }
        

        
        std::cout << " Player X: " << player.getPosition().x / tileSize<< "  Y: " << player.getPosition().y / tileSize << " EndGoal X: " << endGoal.getPosition().x / tileSize << "  Y: " << endGoal.getPosition().y  / tileSize << std::endl;


        window.draw(endGoal);
        player.draw(window);
        window.display();
        
    }

    return 0;
}
```

**Player.h**

```
#pragma once
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

class Player {
public:
    Player(float size) {
        gridSize = size;
        player.setFillColor(sf::Color::Black);
        player.setOutlineThickness(gridSize / 10);
        player.setOutlineColor(sf::Color::Black);
        player.setPosition(sf::Vector2f(gridSize, gridSize));
    }

    void draw(sf::RenderWindow &renderWindow) {

        renderWindow.draw(player);
    }

    void handleMovement() {
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::W)) { player.move(0, -gridSize); }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::S)) { player.move(0, gridSize); }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::A)) { player.move(-gridSize, 0); }
        if (sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Key::D)) { player.move(gridSize, 0); }
    }
    bool isPlayerColliding(sf::RectangleShape &collider) {
        if (player.getPosition() == collider.getPosition())
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }

    sf::Vector2f getPosition() { return player.getPosition(); }
    sf::Vector2f getSize() { return player.getSize(); }

private:
    float gridSize;
    sf::RectangleShape player;
};
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The player is rendering but it's size is (0, 0).

Set the players size in it's constructor.

This might look like:

```cpp
player.setSize(sf::Vector2f(size, size));
```